# Is there a simpler equation for this 2-d Analog to Coefficent of Variation?

Tags: integration, definition, distribution-theory, implicit-function

I'm creating a test that measures how evenly distributed is closed curve $\mathcal{C}$. This requires the average ray length (from point $(u,v)$ to the boundary of the shape) inside $\mathcal{C}$ using ray length per radian measure.

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ can be represented as $(a_1(t),a_2(t))$. We start by finding the average absolute deviation between the ray length and a constant length.

\begin{equation}
\min\limits_{z} \left\{\int\limits_{a_1(p_1)}^{a_1(p_2)}\left|\sqrt{\left(a_1(t)-u\right)^2+\left(a_2(t)-v\right)^2}-z\right| d\theta\right\}
\label{Minimum}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\min\limits_{z} \left\{\int\limits_{a_1(p_1)}^{a_1(p_2)}\left[\left|\sqrt{\left(a_1(t)-u\right)^2+\left(a_2(t)-v\right)^2}-z\right|  \frac{d\theta}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a_2(t)-u}{a_1(t)-v}\right)\right)\right]  dt \right\}
\label{Minimum2}
\end{equation}

Where $a_1(p_1)<t<a_1(p_2)$ parametrizes the entire shape

Here is picture to clarify.

[image: SS]

(Note the blue circle is created by the angular displacement from the rotated tip of the constant length. Once the tips' back in its initial position, the displacement should be $2\pi$ radians. Hence, $(u,v)$ must remain inside the shape for a credible distribution number.)

This can be found by setting the "constant" to the average radius $\overline{r}(u,v)$. Hence we are taking the mean absolute deviation. Say this function, in terms of $(u,v)$ is

\begin{equation} 
 \int\limits_{a_1(p_1)}^{a_1(p_2)}\left[\left|\sqrt{\left(a_1(t)-u\right)^2+\left(a_2(t)-v\right)^2}-\overline{r}(u,v)\right|\frac{d\theta}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a_2(t)-u}{a_1(t)-v}\right)\right)\right]dt
 \label{AverageRadiusIn}
 \end{equation}

In order to keep the radius consistent to curves geometrically similar, we divide the integral by the average radius. This gives us distribution $\phi(u,v)$.

\begin{equation}
\phi(u,v)=\frac{1}{\overline{r}(u,v)}\int\limits_{a_1(p_1)}^{a_1(p_2)}\left[\left|\sqrt{\left(a_1(t)-u\right)^2+\left(a_2(t)-v\right)^2}-\overline{r}(u,v)\right|\frac{d\theta}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a_2(t)-u}{a_1(t)-v}\right)\right)\right]dt
\label{CompleteEquation}
\end{equation}

Which determines how evenly distributed is curve $\mathcal{C}$.

In a post, a code was given to parametrize implicitly defined $\mathcal{C}$ using arclength.

```
     expr = (x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4 x] + Sin[4 y] - 4)^2 + .415 x - .4;
        exprt = expr /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t]};
        odes = {D[exprt, t], x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 - 1}
        starty = y /. FindRoot[(expr /. x -> 0) == 0, {y, 2/9}]
        Quiet[soln = 
           NDSolveValue[
            Join[Thread[odes == 0], {x[0] == 0, y[0] == starty}], {x[t], 
             y[t]}, {t, 0, 25}];]
        {solnX, solnY} = soln;
        ParametricPlot[soln, {t, 0, 25}]
        Plot[(solnX - 0)^2 + (solnY - starty)^2, {t, 0, 25}]
        {min, val} = NMinimize[(solnX - 0)^2 + (solnY - starty)^2, {t, 20, 25}]
        stopt = t /. val;
        r = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
          NIntegrate[
            Sqrt[(solnX - x)^2 + (solnY - y)^2]*
             D[ArcTan[solnX - x, solnY - y], t], {t, 0, stopt}, 
            MaxRecursion -> 100, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]/(2*Pi)]

s = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
  NIntegrate[
    Abs[Sqrt[(solnX - x)^2 + (solnY - y)^2] - r[x, y]]*
     D[ArcTan[solnX - x, solnY - y], t], {t, 0, stopt}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 100, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]/(2*Pi)]
```

The distrbution number is

```
Phi = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, s[x, y]/r[x, y]]
```

However, there is no clear way of determining where to measure $(u,v)$. If we set $(u,v)$ to the centroid, it could be outside the curve and hence the ray won't rotate with an angular displacement of $2\pi$ radians. So where do we set $(u,v)$?

My assumption is to take the average of $\phi(u,v)$ inside $\mathcal{C}$. This leads to a brutal formula.

$$\omega=\frac{1}{\text{Area}\left(\mathcal{C}\right)} \iint\limits_{C} \phi(u,v) \ du \ dv$$

### Question

Is there a simpler way to describe the integral and distribution?

Comment: In the special case where the shape is convex, then you can represent the shape as a bunch of scaled versions of its boundary integrated together.  For this reason, if you have a measurement of the boundary (e.g. the standard deviation in radius or curvature) you can integrate it to get the measurement over the whole shape.

Comment: @user326210 Where can you find this in textbooks?

Comment: @user326210 I edited my answer.